# why solution of first order PDE is constant along characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The method characteristics is a way to reduce a PDE to a system of ODEs, then it is said that solution $u$ of PDE has to be constant along characteristic curves. Basing on this idea we build a solution as a arbitrary function of first integrals. But why we have decided that the solution $u$ is constant along characteristic curves?

Comment: It is an ansatz that works e.g. like to seperation of variables for parabolic PDEs.